# How to click a button in Selenium if its changing its position on web?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to click on button "OK", if it's changing the position dynamically after every run?

I have a button, with every run it's changing the position, but I want to click that button in every run? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a relative xpath combining position, Text, ClassName etc.

Example xpath : `//div[@class='okBtn']/input[contains(.,'OK')]`